# Is there an easy way to open a sidebar item in a new window?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In the OS X Finder there is a sidebar in each window listing commonly-used folders like Documents, Downloads, etc. It’s possible to open one of these folders in a new window by clicking on it while holding down the Command key.

Windows Explorer also shows a sidebar like this. Is there a faster way to open one of the sidebar items in a new window than right-clicking on it and selecting “Open in a new window”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a Windows File Explorer add-on like Clover (http://ejie.me/), to open one of the sidebar links in a new window (or tab in this case) just scroll-click on the item.

There seems to be none defined from Microsoft (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7)

Another alternative could be to create a script using AutoHotkey of which I'm unsure if it's even possible for this scenario.